# PHP Adjust Image brightness of 2 Images

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I have two similar Images, one of it is brighter than the other.
I tried to get a Color or Gamma-Value to handle with -with no results.
As endresult i would like to adjust both Image in same brightness/gamma.

```
<?php
$s1=new Imagick('01.jpg');
$s2=new Imagick('01.jpg');
$gamma=$s1->getImageGamma (); // Output "0" :-(
$s2->setImageGamma($gamma);
?>
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Do you realise, you haven't actually asked a question? Also - http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/gammaImage